# Как скопировать картинку в нужную мне папкку и одновременно поставаить ее в QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно, что при нажатии на кнопки вылезало окно с поиском картинки. И после подтверждения она копировалась в нужную мне папку. И затем вставала в QLabel. Знаю, что это делается через QFileDialog и `shutil.copyfile()`. Но чет не получается. Выручайте.

Для тех, кому интересно вот код:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import shutil
from os import getcwd
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label_image = QLabel()
        self.label_image.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 64, 64))
        self.label_image.show()

        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setGeometry(QRect(100, 10, 60, 23))
        self.button.setText('Select image')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        self.button.show()

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_image)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def Sopy(self, path):
        shutil.copyfile(path, 'E:\\Example\\psth_out.png')
        self.Set_Icon()

    def seleccionarImagen(self):
        imagen, extension = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выбор картинки", getcwd(),
            "Image (*.png)",
            options=QFileDialog.Options())
        if imagen == '':
            return
        self.Sopy(imagen)

    def Set_Icon(self):
        pixmapImagen = QPixmap('E:\\Example\\psth_out.png').scaled(128, 128, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.label_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmapImagen))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(200, 200)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

В принципе все работает, но при условии, что при копировании в E:\Example\psth_out.png есть уже файл .png, а как сделать, чтобы если его там нет, то создать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может можно сденлать попроще, но пока что что первое в голову пришло

```
import sys
import os
import string
import random
import shutil
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        but = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Нажми без модуля shutil")
        but.clicked.connect(self.save_img_standard)
        but_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Нажми с модулем shutil")
        but_2.clicked.connect(self.save_img_shutil)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(but)
        layout.addWidget(but_2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def save_img_standard(self):
        self.img = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter="*.jpg *.png *.gif")[0]
        if self.img:
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.img))
            with open("{}/{}{}".format(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(),
                                       "".join([random.choice(number_random) for _ in range(3)]),
                                       os.path.splitext(self.img)[1]), "wb") as a, open(self.img, "rb") as img:
                a.write(img.read())

    def save_img_shutil(self):
        self.img = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter="*.jpg *.png *.gif")[0]
        if self.img:
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.img))
            shutil.copy2(self.img, "{}/{}{}".format(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(),
                                                    "".join([random.choice(number_random) for _ in range(3)]),
                                                    os.path.splitext(self.img)[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_random = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `"{}/{}{}".format...` зачем так усложнять? :) возьмите `os.path.basename(self.img)` и добавьте его в путь текущей папке, тогда и по условию вопроса будет работать, и кода станет меньше и он будет проще, хотя бы так: `dir_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()` `file_name = dir_name + '/' + os.path.basename(self.img)`